# How to remove top 4 outliers in my pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

## PLease help me to Filter out the 4 outliers

Many codes from chatgpt but still not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ9We.png)

Comment: "*Many codes from chatgpt but still not working*" -> did you expect otherwise?

Comment: [without the outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu0po.jpg)

Comment: Can you show me the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
Q1 = df.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
df = df[~((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR))|(newdf > (Q3 + 1.5*IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

Also you can remove outliers special columns: df['colname'].

Comment: I did this twice seems like drop more than 4 outliers

max_total_rooms = df['total_rooms'].max()
df = df[df['total_rooms'] != max_total_rooms]

max_total_rooms = df['total_rooms'].max()
df1 = df[df['total_rooms'] != max_total_rooms]

Comment: Use only one, if you use two or more it's removed more info.

Comment: You can also .loc function.

Comment: max_population = df['population'].max()
max_total_rooms = df['total_rooms'].max()

# filter the DataFrame to exclude rows where 'population' equals the maximum value
df = df.loc[df['population'] != max_population]

# filter the DataFrame to exclude rows where 'total_rooms' equals the maximum value
df = df.loc[df['total_rooms'] != max_total_rooms]

Comment: df = df.loc[df['population'] < 20000]  it's population filter

Comment: can you type the entire code for me please

Comment: Yes, please send me plot picture and red scatter where need remove.

Comment: I got it some how using,max_population = df['population'].nlargest(2).index

# create a copy of the DataFrame without the two maximum values in the 'population' column
df_no_pop_outliers = df.loc[~df.index.isin(max_population)]

# find the two maximum values in the 'total_rooms' column
max_total_rooms = df_no_pop_outliers['total_rooms'].nlargest(2).index

# create a set of indices to remove
outlier_indices = set(max_population).union(set(max_total_rooms))

# filter the DataFrame to exclude the outlier rows
df = df.loc[~df.index.isin(outlier_indices)]

Comment: Very good, okay